# Secure TCP chat app with encryption of messages C#, AES, RSA

Tags: cryptography, chat, aes, rsa

I am trying to build TCP Chat application in C#. So far I managed to build working Chat application and to crypt messages that should be sent through the app with AES algorithm.

Now I would like to encrypt the password used for AES with RSA algorithm.

Comment: Is this just a personal or school project?

Comment: It is a personal project. I am trying to create safe chat app where messages are protected with AES algorithm and AES key for decrypting messages is protected/encrypted with RSA algorithm.

Comment: Take a look as the Signal protocol by Open Whisper Systems
 which is generally accepted to be secure. [Private Group Messaging](https://whispersystems.org/blog/private-groups/), [Technical Documentation](https://whispersystems.org/docs/) and the Open Whisper Systems [GitHub repository](https://github.com/whispersystems/)

Comment: I already finished the chat app and it works fine, I managed to add AES encryption for the messages sent via chat and a button to decrypt the messages. Now I want to encrypt AES password with RSA algorithm.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Use a pre-existing protocol such as whisperor just plain TLS. If you think you have any security by just applying AES then you are *dead* wrong. You need a full transport protocol, with authentication, key derivation, MAC ... the whole shebang.